# Join only lines with minimal value in specific field

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, abap

My aim is to left join the tables 'anla' and 'anlz' but only include all the lines where the value of the field 'bdatu' of anlz is minimal.

I created a SQL fiddle with the schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3ab2/5

Unfortunately I need it for an ABAP program with an Oracle database, not MySQL, so [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3ab2/5) doesn't work for me. I added the MySQL tag to this to get some more input and possible solutions.

Table anla:

```
anln1 |  anln2
--------------
10000 |  0
10000 |  1
10000 |  2
10000 |  3
10001 |  0
10001 |  1
10001 |  2
10002 |  0
10003 |  0
10004 |  0
10005 |  0
10005 |  1
10006 |  0
10006 |  1
10007 |  0
10007 |  1
```

Table anlz:

```
anln1 | anln2 | kostlv | bdatu
---------------------------------
10000 |  0    | 123    | 20001231
10000 |  0    | 456    | 99991231
10000 |  1    | 123    | 99991231
10000 |  2    | 456    | 99991231
10000 |  3    | 789    | 99991231
10001 |  0    | 123    | 99991231
10001 |  1    | 123    | 99991231
10001 |  2    | 123    | 99991231
10002 |  0    | 123    | 99991231
10003 |  0    | 456    | 99991231
10004 |  0    | 123    | 99991231
10005 |  0    | 123    | 99991231
10005 |  1    | 456    | 99991231
10006 |  0    | 123    | 20001231
10006 |  0    | 456    | 99991231
10006 |  1    | 123    | 99991231
10007 |  0    | 123    | 20001231
10007 |  0    | 123    | 99991231
10007 |  1    | 123    | 99991231
```

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Just to be clear, what's the desired result? Also, both anla and anlz appear to have an id column which you've excluded above.

Answer (score 1):

you almost had it,minor tweak needed :

```
SELECT DISTINCT anla.anln1, anla.anln2, z.kostlv, z.bdatu
FROM anla
LEFT OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT anlz.anln1, anlz.kostlv, min(anlz.bdatu) as bdatu /* note this here*/
              FROM anlz
              GROUP BY anlz.anln1
              HAVING MIN( anlz.bdatu ) > 0 ) AS Z
on anla.anln1= z.anln1
```

you just need to pick `min(anlz.bdatu)` as well in your sub-query!

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3ab2/41)

**Output**

```
ANLN1   ANLN2   KOSTLV  BDATU

10000    0       123    20001231
10000    1       123    20001231
10000    2       123    20001231
10000    3       123    20001231
10001    0       123    99991231
10001    1       123    99991231
10001    2       123    99991231
10002    0       123    99991231
10003    0       456    99991231
10004    0       123    99991231
10005    0       123    99991231
10005    1       123    99991231
10006    0       123    20001231
10006    1       123    20001231
10007    0       123    20001231
10007    1       123    20001231
```

Logic is simple here, pick `min` `bdatu` in inner query as well, that would help out the outer query

Answer (score 0):

The same can be acheived in oracle using subquery factoring

kindly try the below

```
with sub as 
    (SELECT anlz.anln1, anlz.kostlv,(SELECT min(anlz1.bdatu) bdatu
     from 
     anlz anlz1
     where    anlz.anln1=anlz1.anln1
    GROUP BY anlz1.anln1
    HAVING MIN( anlz1.bdatu ) > 0) ) 
     as bdatu
     from anlz 
     ) 
     SELECT DISTINCT a nla.anln1, anla.anln2,      sub.kostlv, sub.bdatu
FROM anla
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub
ON anla.anln1 =  sub.anln1
```